# Class java.beans.PropertyChangeListener not supported by the GWT

Tags: java, gwt, javabeans

I am porting a GWT application from GWT-Ext to SmartGWT. Previously, it used `java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent` and `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`. We recently upgraded to GWT2.4. Am I missing a library? In Netbeans, it is underlined yellow and the hint says

> Class java.beans.PropertyChangeListener not supported by the GWT

Comment: It's possible that the emulation for those classes was provided by GWT-Ext.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: I just discovered that the project used GWTx which emulated it for us. Is there an alternative to PropertyChangeListener in GWT now? Previously we were using GWT 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWTx svn indicates that it was last changed in 2009.

Your best bet is to try recompiling GWTx source code with GWT 2.4 or 2.5 by taking a checkout of the source code from http://gwtx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
( This would help validate whether that jar is compatible latest GWT architecture).